# Reading in configuration file with object structure c#

Tags: c#, object, templates, configuration

I need to store a standard record structure in a template file that can be loaded in by a c# program. The record structure relates to a new entry in a database.

Each new entry has:
 - a header which has a list of values for that table, and
 - a list of items that link to the new entry

Now, here's the tricky part. 
- Each item can itself have a list of sub-items (that are all item type)

The program should load in the template, create a new record, and then process each item one at a time. If the item contains a list of sub-items, those will be processed before the parent item is completed.

I was thinking I could perhaps achieve this using JSON?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stackoverflow. You should know that stackoverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service. Please, show us what you have try so far. Any search attempts or code samples? Also, it is not clear what you actually asking for. Your only question is _"I was thinking I could perhaps achieve this using JSON?"_ - and the answer is _"Yes, you can."_

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you code for doing this but may be enough pointers.

1. Design the Class that should represent your Record. Ex:

If my record is that of an Employee

```
public class Employee
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string EmpId {get; set;}
 public Link<Jobs> JobHistory {get; set;}
}
```

2. Read about Serializers. Using them you can convert objects to Binary, Xml, Json etc. formats. So this is key for getting the state/stuff that needs to be persisted.
3. Read about File handling stuff in System.IO. File.Write/Read methods. Also, how to use these along with Serializers (may need to read on MemoryStream/StreamReader/Writers etc). This will help you write the persistable state into file system.

Comment: 2: basic knowledge about serializers is good, but please, don't reinvent a bicycle - use existing libraries ([Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) for example) 3: again, this basic knowledge is also helpful, but there is [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes), [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext) and [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines), so don't mess with streams when you don't need them

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Prateek Shrivastava,

Lists was the solution I was looking for.

I tried storing the data as JSON, but worked out better to create a few additional tables in the database, and write an app to create and edit templates.

Using JSON.NET for the serialisation and deserialisation.